# Browser Issue when popup childwindow in silverlight 4 application

Tags: silverlight

I am having silverlight 4 application in which i am able to pop up childwindow on button click in IE but it does not work in mozilla plz help me

Thanks 
Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

Make sure FireFox is not blocking the popup.